# Equivalent replace method SQL in mongoDB spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm looking for a request in `spring data mongodb` that looks something like this :

```
 ?#{ [2] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'vehicle.immatriculation' : {'$regex' : {'$replaceAll':[2],'-',''}, $options : 'x'} } }"
```

is it possible to make this type of request? I'm stuck because I can't find an equivalent to replace `SQL`

EDITION

In `SQL`

```sql
    SELECT colonne1, colonne2, REPLACE(colonne3, '-', '')
    FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

That function doesn't exist quite yet.  [SERVER-32314](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32314) is a feature request to add `$replaceOne` and `$replaceAll` as aggregation operators.  It looks like this request might be in the next release, but it did not make the cut for MongoDB 4.2

That server ticket also offers a workaround.  I adapted that example to your structure, but I'm not familiar enough with Spring to give you that syntax.  Here it is in mongo shell javascript, perhaps someone else can translate this to Java.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{
  _id:0,
  colonne1:1, 
  colonne2:1, 
  colonne3:{$let:{
     vars:{split:{$split:["$colonne3","-"]}},
     in:{$reduce:{
        input:{$slice:["$$split",1,{$size:"$$split"}]},
        initialValue:{$arrayElemAt:["$$split",0]},
        in:{$concat:["$$value","$$this"]}
     }}
  }}
}}])
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have use a alternative solution for this problem while waiting for this to be updated